# Can I submit a paper to a journal that is already on arXiv under a public domain license?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, arxiv

Is there any problem in submitting a preprint to a journal while this preprint is already on arXiv with the public domain license (which was selected by mistake)?

If so, how can I solve this knowing that arXiv doesn't withdraw published papers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I chose wrong license during submission on arXiv, what shall I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57052/i-chose-wrong-license-during-submission-on-arxiv-what-shall-i-do)

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/151558/68109

Comment: it helps somehow, but we submit our preprint to the world scientific publisher which is on arxiv with cc0 license, the world scienfic publisher indicate that "Authors may post their submitted manuscript (preprint) at any time on their personal website, in their company or institutional repository, in not-for-profit subject-based preprint servers or repositories, and on scholarly collaboration networks (SCNs) which have signed up to the STM sharing principles. Please provide the following acknowledgement along with a link to the article via its DOI if available."

Comment: i don't now is that ok with the cc0 license on arxiv or will have a problem as the arxiv has a preprint not an accepted or published paper

Comment: Don't submit to publishers which don't allow you to post your work on the arxiv.

Comment: Indeed the publisher allow for arxiv but I am not sure if they are OK with the chosen liscence in arxiv which is a public domain because we must transfer our copy right to them after acceptance

Comment: Just ask the journal editor if they're OK with it or not, as was done in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/119562/17254) (albeit with a CC-BY license).

Comment: Thanks a lot we just waiting their reply, if they have a problem how to solve it. Is there journal's accepting this liscence or may be rewriting the paper again could help?

Comment: For example, an open access journal is unlikely to have a problem with this.

Comment: Thank u. Does letting this preprint as it is and rewriting the paper is a solution to publish in non open access journals?